# How to access API's from smart contract deployed on Ropston network from local Machine?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten

I want to access API's from a smart contract deployed on Ropsten network. This smart contract is written and deployed by some external entity and they have exposed API's.
I know the smart contract address, solidity file (as source code is open),API's to call. I want to know by which way i can connect Ropsten network from my local machine and call required API's.

Their documentations are not clear, so even after trying multiple options i could not able to make it.

Please let me know if is there any way to do this. Let me know if require any further information

Answer (score 1):

I understand that by 'API' you mean the contract functions.
There are several ways:

Option 1: MyEtherwallet (or myCrypto):

Find contract ABI:

`solc --abi contractSourceCode.sol`

Go to: https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts

Enter the contract address, the contract ABI and press 'access'.
You will be able to interact with the contract

Option 2: Use `geth` and Infura

Register at infura.io and get a token

Connect to ropsten using Infura

`geth attach https://ropsten.infura.io/<your-token>`

Now that you are in a geth console:

`var cont = eth.contract(<contract ABI>).at(<contract address>)`

Then, you can run the contract functions by:

`cont.functionName()`

Where "functionName" is any function the contract has (note that writing `cont.` and pressing `tab` will autocomplete.

There are other ways, but for me those 2 are the simplest ones.

Answer (score 1):

If the contract is verified in etherscan (as you mentioned it is open), then you just go to "write contract" section. And call any functions.